# Gostaria de colocar minha ESP32 em modo low energy, estou tentando implementar o BLE

Tags: c++, bluetooth

O meu código está bem padrão como o do exemplo, do vídeo que estou seguindo, porém está dando um erro de compilação, onde fala

[Complilation error: BLECharacteristi(nome dado a ela) does not name a type: did you mean 'Character_h'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoSL9.png)

sendo que estou colocando ela antes do void setup. E quando coloco no void setup, aparece erro de não foi declarada no escopo

[Compilation error: 'BLECharacteristic' was not declared in this scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1txJ.png)

```
BLECharacteristic customCharacteristic(
   BLEUUID((uint16_t)0x1700),
   BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
   BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY |
   BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
 );
```

Answer (score -3):

O erro "BLECharacteristic does not name a type" indica que o compilador não reconhece o tipo BLECharacteristic, que é uma classe da biblioteca BLE da ESP32. Isso pode ocorrer se você não incluiu a biblioteca BLE corretamente no seu código.

Certifique-se de que a linha #include <BLEDevice.h> está presente no início do seu código, antes da definição da classe BLECharacteristic. Isso deve garantir que o compilador reconheça o tipo BLECharacteristic.

Se o problema persistir, verifique se você instalou a biblioteca BLE corretamente em sua instalação do Arduino IDE. Você pode verificar isso indo em "Sketch" -> "Include Library" e procurando por "ESP32 BLE Arduino" na lista de bibliotecas instaladas. Se a biblioteca não estiver instalada, você pode instalá-la selecionando "ESP32 BLE Arduino" na lista de bibliotecas disponíveis e clicando em "Install".

Além disso, certifique-se de que está usando a versão mais recente da biblioteca BLE, já que versões mais antigas podem não ter o tipo BLECharacteristic. Você pode verificar isso na página da biblioteca no GitHub.

Certifique-se de incluir a biblioteca BLE no início do seu código com o seguinte comando:

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
```

Além disso, verifique se você incluiu as bibliotecas necessárias para as outras variáveis e classes usadas no seu código. Certifique-se de que todas as bibliotecas relevantes estão incluídas no início do seu código.

Quanto à implementação do modo de baixa energia, você pode usar o seguinte comando para colocar a ESP32 em modo de baixa energia:

```
esp_sleep_enable_esp32_wakeup();
esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_PERIPH, ESP_PD_OPTION_AUTO);
esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_SLOW_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_ON);
esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_FAST_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_ON);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

Este comando ativa a configuração do RTC (Relógio em Tempo Real) para que a ESP32 possa ser despertada em um horário específico. Em seguida, ele configura os diferentes domínios de energia (RTC Periféricos, RTC Slow Memory e RTC Fast Memory) para que a energia possa ser gerenciada de forma eficiente. Por fim, ele coloca a ESP32 em modo de baixa energia usando o comando esp_deep_sleep_start(). Lembre-se de que, para acordar a ESP32 após o modo de baixa energia, você precisará usar um pino ou temporizador externo para enviar um sinal de despertar para a ESP32.